# Get terms that don't belong to current post with a shortcode

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Is it possible to retrieve all the terms of a custom hierarchical taxonomy that do *not* belong to the current post? Perhaps by using `wp_get_post_terms()`? I recently stumbled upon this unusual need.

Basically, if my custom taxonomy contain the terms (term1, term2, term3, etc.), I want to show in the single post page that this post belongs to term1 and term2 but not term3 etc.

**EDIT:**
I am having difficulty implementing this in a shortcode. I have this code:

```
add_shortcode( 'my-no-terms', 'no_terms_func' );
function no_terms_func() {
    $this_post_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'my-tax-slug' );
    $exclude = wp_list_pluck( $this_post_terms, 'term_id' );
    $args = array(
        'exclude' => $exclude, 
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'my-tax-slug', $args );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        return $term->name;
    }
}
```

But this is only outputting the first term, not the whole list of terms. Where's the culprit?

Comment: The culprit is `return $term->name`. From the PHP manual: "If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function" --> Hence your `foreach` loop never gets past one iteration. Collect the terms in a [concatenated string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Return that after iterating over them.

Comment: As an aside, the above basically answers a new question - Milo's below answer covered your initial question entirely - it hence should be accepted, IMHO.

Comment: @JohannesPille My bad, you're definitely correct. I just accepted the answer. Also I managed to solve the shortcode issue with concatenated string as you've suggested. Thank for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the term IDs of the current post terms in an array, and pass that as the `exclude` parameter to the [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function.

```
$this_post_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'your_custom_tax' );
$exclude = wp_list_pluck( $this_post_terms, 'term_id' );
$args = array(
    'exclude' => $exclude, 
);
$terms = get_terms( 'your_custom_tax', $args );
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about `wp_list_pluck`! Cool function I didn't know about. I've updated my question, please see.

Comment: Never mind, all good now